# How to trigger ngOnChanges

Tags: angular, onchange

How to trigger ngOnChanges on a form in a component?

I want to calculate a new total price (gesamtpreis) whenever any form input changes.

I looked at other answers, but this just made my code more weird instead of working. Do I need the @Input and is it correctly wired.

component HTML:

```
<div class="card my-5">
<div class="card-body">

<form #carConfigurationForm="ngForm" ng-change="ngOnChanges">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="extra">Extra 1&nbsp;</label>
    <select name="extra1" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle">
      <option value="default">Kein Extra</option>
      <option *ngFor="let extra of selectExtra" [value]="extra.name">{{extra.name}} {{extra.preis}}&euro;</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="gesamtpreis">Gesamt&nbsp;</label>
    <span name="gesamtpreis" [innerHTML]="gesamtpreis"></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Extra } from '../model/extra';
import { ExtraService} from '../service/extra.service';
import { SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-car-configuration-form',
  templateUrl: './car-configuration-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./car-configuration-form.component.sass']
})
export class CarConfigurationFormComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  selectExtra : Extra[] = [];

  gesamtpreis : string = 'kein Preis';

  constructor(private extraService: ExtraService) { }

  getSelectedExtra(): void{
    this.extraService.findAll()
      .subscribe(selectExtra => this.selectExtra= selectExtra);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getSelectedExtra();

  }

  @Input() extra1: string = '';

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // changes.prop contains the old and the new value...
    console.log('zzz ngOnChanges');
    this.gesamtpreis = "zzz"; //changes.toString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ngModel

Why do you want to use ngOnChanges exactly?

You can just use `ngModel` to bind to values in a template form:

```html
<select name="extra1" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" [ngModel]="gesamtpreis">
```

If you want other logic to trigger when the value changes you can just make getters and setters for that value:

```js
private _gesamtpreis = 'kein Preis';

get gesamtpreis() {
  return this._gesamtpreis
}

set gesamtpreis(value) {
  this._gesamtpreis = value
  /* Some other logic goes here... */
  /* You could event push to a subject here, whatever floats your boat... */
}
```

### Binding to the (change) event

```html
<form #carConfigurationForm="ngForm" (change)="formChanged(carConfigurationForm)">
```

Script:

```js
formChanged(event) {
    console.log(event.value)
}
```

*In your case you don't even need to pass the form reference into the function. Since it seems you only want to get some notice of the form being changed.*

Here's a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wafeas?file=src/app/app.component.html) for you to play with.

Comment: Okay, i learned about ngModel. But ngOnChanges still isn't triggered. I want to use it to recalculate the total price (gesamtpreis) whenever any of the form fields change (extra1, but later more).

Comment: You can just do that recalculation in the setter.

Comment: @Adder I gave you another option to achieve what you want and updated the Stackblitz too.

Comment: This second option does what I expected the code to do. I now just need to clean up after all experiments I did

Answer (score 4):

`ngOnChanges` is not triggered because it is meant for component that recieves `@Input`. It is a life cycle hook that gets triggered when `@input` binded to some component is changed or reset.

Even if your component had some `input` binded, you wouldn't be able to detect changes on form, because form is a native dom element for your component, you don't receive it via input.

`ngOnChanges` performs change check only on the data that is recieved via `input`

You can subscribe to `Form.valueChanges` for this.

Comment: I tried using a formGroup as suggested, but i just get " Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'." I was looking at https://blog.logrocket.com/reactive-form-controls-form-groups-angular/ for inspiration

Comment: Oh you read that? i deleted that thinking it was too much info... That is probably because you don't have import of `ReactiveFormsModule` in your `app.module.ts`

Comment: I added the import to app.module and component, but neither does remove the error. The form element now reads "<form [formGroup]="carConfigurationFormGroup">"

Comment: give me a min i'll make an example of stackblitz for you

Comment: there you go https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-slhvft?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for the blitz, i managed to remove the error by adding ReactiveFormsModule in import and module initialization

Answer (score 1):

Forms possess a property `valueChanges` to which you can subscribe.

you could do

```js
  // declare the variable referencing the ngForm
  @ViewChild('carConfigurationForm') carConfigurationForm: NgForm;

  selectedExtra: Extra[] = [];
```

and then

```js
ngOnInit() {
   this.getSelectedExtra();
   this.carConfigurationForm.form.valueChanges.subscribe((newValue: any) => {
      console.log('old value:', carConfigurationForm.form.value);
      console.log('new value:', newValue);
    });
}
```

Comment: I get "Parameter 'newValue' implicitly has an 'any' type." error. And I need the form to have updated values (after valueChanges) so I can calculate a price total when I added more fields to the form

Comment: I've edited my answer. I don't have the possibility to test it right here but adding the type should solve your error message (replacing `newValue` by `(newValue: any)`)

Comment: It compiles now, but it still doesn't react to changes made to the select dropdown.

Comment: right, I hadn't read your code thoroughly enough. @H3AR7B3A7's answer is more adapted to your question